# Secretary Problem - Optimal algorithm for expected value of candidate.

Tags: probability, expectation, stopping-times

I recently encountered the secretary problem and there are essentiall two problems:

1. Maximizing the probability of choosing the best candidate.
   Gnedin proved in his paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176988613
   the following:

*There exists no algorithm, which can choose the best candidate with probability better than* $\frac{1}{e}$.

2. Maximizing the expected value of the candidate. So, basically if we don't get the best candidate, we like to get at least a fairly good candidate, who is not too much worse than the best candidate.

Do you think the following statement will also hold true:

*There exists no algorithm, which chooses a candidate whose value ("talent") is better than $\frac{1}{e} \cdot c^{best}$, where as $c^{best} = max\{c_1,...,c_n\}.$*

I haven't found any proof for this statement yet. I wonder, whether it can be proved by using the statement for the first problem. 
If you have any papers or any ideas, which can help me, this would be great!

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by $c^{best}$. If it is supposed to be a rank then $c^{best}=1$, by definition.

Comment: You are right, I think of another word instead of rank.By $c^{best}$ I basically mean the value or "talent" of the best candidate, thus $c^{best} = max\{c_1, ... , c_n\}$.

Comment: In this way it becomes a totally different problem. You would have to make assumptions about the distribution of talents.

Comment: I don't quite understand, why I would be needing assumptions on the distributions of talents. Can't we just assume it is an arbitary distribution given? Would you mind elaborating this point? And what if I choose the same distribution as Gnedin has taken?